# How to properly render a curve/thin object in Cycles?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, bezier-curves

I was rendering a bezier curve made on Blender Cycles in 4K resolution but it looks pretty awful, it looks too pixelated and the image doesnt even looks like the curve on preview, how can i configure this?

[image]

Comment: So it's only a problem with the Renderer, not the resolution or something of the curve?

Comment: It just looks like a render with a low number of samples to me, which makes the render noisy. If you render any object with the same material it should have a similar grainy appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Two setting for the curve you need to change, to change the curve's resolution.

First to add more loops along the length of the curve change the *Resolution* of the curve.
The *Preview* setting controls the amount of loops displayed in the 3D view. The *Render* setting controls how many get rendered, if it is set to 0, then the *Preview* number is used.

To add more points around the circumference of the curve change the *Resolution* of the *Bevel*.

[image: curve settings]